# Accepted answer appearing below most voted answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, accepted-answer

In [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3804/how-do-i-prevent-a-website-being-misclassified-by-websense), the current accepted answer appears below the most voted answer:

[image]

---

**Notes:** it is surviving refreshs, using FireFox

Comment: Tangent: the fact that this question ends up being a conversation (highly unlikely to be one just any site owner could replicate), may need to be revisited for an answer which is applicable to sites other than the SE network's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's working correctly. If the accepted answer was posted by the same user that asked the question, it isn't pinned to the top.

[Answer with more upvotes appears above accepted answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23051/166045)

[Default “order by” of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110465/166045)

[How are answers sorted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107098/166045) (see comments)